How to use managed identity or some other permanent auth for a VM not on Azure?
I have a Discord bot that I use to turn on/off Azure VMs, and currently this bot authenticates to Azure using an access token I generate using an az CLI command. However this means that every now and then I have to regenerate the token, which is annoying. I'd like to use something permanent like managed identity, but this bot doesn't run on Azure, it runs on a local k8s cluster and I'd like to keep it that way. Is there any way permanent way of authenticating the bot against Azure so that I don't have to keep regenerating an auth token?

Azure Managed Identity functions only when the code is executed within the same VM. If the code runs outside the VM, it will not work. In such cases, you can use a Service Principal, which serves a similar purpose for identities operating outside of the VM.

Besides Service Principals there is another way. Federated Credentials - but this is more complex to maintain for a single application
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/federatedidentitycredentials-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0
Especially with Kubernetes you can use Workload identity - but that again would require an app registration.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/workload-identity-overview?tabs=dotnet

Create a Service Principal with either a secret (key) or certificate for authentication. Then store that (securely) on your k8s cluster and use it to log on to Azure and get auth tokens: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/sdk/identity-service-principal-auth
